# Send email to users gmail contacts or yahoo mail contacts or LinkedIn connections

Tags: facebook, gmail, linkedin-api, yahoo

I am working on website with symfony where users create a page which is publicly viewable and I need to do something so that the users can send an email to their gmail or yahoo or LinkedIn or Facebook contacts(they can choose to whom the mail should go, it's like sending invitations to their mail contacts) about the site saying all about its greatness. I have no idea on what this process called or how to do this ? Do I need to use any Apis or ?

Comment: at least for facebook contacts, this is not possible. you cannot get the email of the friends on facebook, luckily. either way, what you want to do sounds super-spammy.

Comment: @luschn edited my question. It's not the spammy thing. They can send a mail to spread the word about the site like sending joining invitations to their mail contacts like in twitter

Comment: alright, i will create an answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done with several invitation channels:

- simple email input field
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button - with Facebook App, but no API call needed, you can just create the code with the code generator

Not sure if there is a possibility to share something with specific LinkedIn accounts, but i assume that you need to use their API: https://developer.linkedin.com/apis